# Mapping sixaxis motion sensors to keyboard in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, game-controller

I'm writing an Ubuntu application for stereoscopic augmented reality using a head mounted display and a DS3 sixaxis in place of traditional mag tracers for head tracking:

[image]

To save myself a lot of extra work I would like to use the keyboard for translational movement and the mouse for rotation much like in a video game. This way I would just have to map the motion sensors from the sixaxis to the appropriate keys.

Does anyone know of software that can do this? Since I've got the controller already paired and jtest is detecting the motion sensors, I think I could use any package that can map a gamepad to the keyboard but I'm not certain on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a bunch of these a while back but the only one I found that did well with the motion sensor was joy2key. You can find the project at

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/joy2key/

You just have to make sure you don't block synthetic events in your code. Your project sounds awesome by the way I hope you'll put it up somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, Nathan, I had that in my pile but hadn't tried it yet. I found a couple more that work but not nearly as well. BTW I'm going to put my project on sourceforge probably later this week. When I do I'll put a link to it on my user page if you're interested.